# C# and VB.net in one VSTO-Ribbon for Excel - is it possible?

Tags: vsto

C# and VB.net in one VSTO-Ribbon for Excel - is it possible ?
Just like one Excel-tab on C # and another one on VB. net ?
Or something else but with C # and VB .net in one project ?

Comment: You cannot easily combine C# and VB in one "project".  But you can make 2 addins.

Comment: Can I make 2 addins in one Project ?

Comment: No; you need to make two projects.

Comment: ok ( but is is the way to use in one Ribbon C# and VB.net ? It's ok if it's not easy way....

Comment: 2 addins can contribute items to the same ribbon tab.

Comment: Great! do you have some example or link ? write me please !

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Is it possible to locate 2 Projects (C# and VB) into one Solution and create references into each other and Published them somehow ?

Answer (score 0):

Source code in the same project can NOT be mixed.  You can create a project in C# and a VB.NET project under the same solution.